# get form object from outside <form> tags

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to grab a form object from an external javascript function instead of passing it from a submit button inside the  tags.

So for example lets say my form is:

```
<form id="form1">
 //inputs...
</form>
```

Normally I would just put a button in there with onClick="submitFunction(this.form)" to pass it to my javascript function, however now I'd like to be able to grab all that form data from an external function, but obviously "this.form" doesn't work outside the form tags.

There's probably a simple way to do this I am overlooking?

Thanks

Comment: aside: don't use a button `onclick` to catch form submissions. In *some* cases, pressing Enter in the form can submit it without a button onclick being called. Use `onsubmit` on the form element itself instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getElementById`

```
function submitForm(){
    your_form = document.getElementById('form1');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And there comes power of jQuery...

$('#form1') ...

$('#form1 input') ...

$('#form1').submit(function() { $(this)... }

Comment: i think he is looking for javascript

Comment: The sheer power of loading kilobytes of JS in order to cut two thirds of the typing needed to get document.getElementById(). It really isn't worth it unless you are doing relatively significant things with JS and want to refactor at least a large chunk of it to use jQuery.

Comment: @June R: jQuery **is** JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
submitFunction(document.getElementById("form1"))
```